# res.render('users/sign_up', options), url should stay at /sign_up

Tags: node.js, express

In Express.js 4, I am rendering a view with file location at users/sign_up.

So I want to use

`res.render('users/sign_up', options)`

However, I am noticing that the url also changes to '/users/sign_up'.

How do I make sure that when I render 'users/sign_up', the URL stays as just '/sign_up'.

Thanks.

Comment: `res.render` itself has no control over the URL whatsoever. Something else in your code is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the actual url is specified elsewhere.  In Express it may look like this:

```
app.get('/sign_up', function(req, res, next){
    options = {...};
    res.render('users/sign_up', options);
});
```